# How do you track database changes in source control?

Tags: sql-server, svn, version-control, sourcegear-vault

We use SQL Server 2000/2005 and Vault or SVN on most of our projects. I haven't found a decent solution for capturing database schema/proc changes in either source control system.

Our current solution is quite cumbersome and difficult to enforce (script out the object you change and commit it to the database).

We have a lot of ideas of how to tackle this problem with some custom development, but I'd rather install an existing tool (paid tools are fine).

So: how do you track your database code changes? Do you have any recommended tools?

---

**Edit:**

Thanks for all the suggestions. Due to time constraints, I'd rather not roll my own here. And most of the suggestions have the flaw that they require the dev to follow some procedure.

Instead, an ideal solution would monitor the SQL Database for changes and commit any detected changes to SCM. For example, if SQL Server had an add-on that could record any DML change with the user that made the change, then commit the script of that object to SCM, I'd be thrilled.

We talked internally about two systems: 
  1. In SQL 2005, use object permissions to restrict you from altering an object until you did a "checkout". Then, the checkin procedure would script it into the SCM.
  2. Run a scheduled job to detect any changes and commit them (anonymously) to SCM.

It'd be nice if I could skip the user-action part and have the system handle all this automatically.

Comment: Coding horror on this topic: https://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use Visual studio database edition to script out your database. Works like a charm and you can use any Source control system, of course best if it has VS plugins. This tool has also a number of other useful features. Check them out here in this great blog post

http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2008/01/Handling-Database-easily-with-Visual-Studio-2008.aspx

or check out MSDN for the official documentation

Answer (score 6):

Tracking database changes directly from SSMS is possible using various 3rd party tools. [ApexSQL Source Control](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_source_control.aspx) automatically scripts any database object that is included in versioning. Commits cannot be automatically performed by the tool. Instead, the user needs to choose which changes will be committed.

When getting changes from a repository, ApexSQL Source Control is aware of a SQL database referential integrity. Thus, it will create a synchronization scripts including all dependent objects that will be wrapped in a transactions so, either all changes will be applied in case no error is encountered, or none of the selected changes is applied. In any case, database integrity remains unaffected.

Answer (score 5):

I have to say I think a visual studio database project is also a reasonable solution to the source control dilemma. If it's set up correctly you can run the scripts against the database from the IDE.  If your script is old,  get the latest,  run it against the DB.  Have a script that recreates all the objects as well if you need,  new objects must be added to the this script as well by hand,  but only once

I like every table, proc and function to be in it's own file.

Comment: +1, thanks! TT beat you to this answer so I accepted that one.

Answer (score 3):

One poor man's solution would be to add a pre-commit hook script that dumps out the latest db schema into a file and have that file committed to your SVN repository along with your code.  Then, you can diff the db schema files from any revision.

Answer (score 1):

I just commit the SQL-alter-Statement additional to the complete SQL-CreateDB-statement.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL2000 **generate each object into it's own file**, then check them all into your source control. Let your source control handle the change history.

In SQL 2005, you'll need to write a bit of code to generate all objects into separate files.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, but you might consider quantifying the number of hours spent manually generating files and come up with a total cost to help justify the purchase of a tool to automate that process. :)

Answer (score 1):

Rolling your own from scratch would not be very doable, but if you use a sql comparison tool like [Redgate SQL Compare SDK](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Comparison_SDK/index.htm) to generate your change files for you it would not take very long to half-roll what you want and then just check those files into source control.  I rolled something similar for myself to update changes from our development systems to our live systems in just a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

In our environment, we never change the DB manually: all changes are done by scripts at release time, and the scripts are kept in the version control system. One important part of this procedure is to be sure that all scripts can be run again against the same DB the scripts are idempotent?) without loss of data. For example, if you add a column, make sure that you do nothing if the column is already there.

Your comment about "suggestions have the flaw that they require the dev to follow some procedure" is really a tell-tale. It's not a flaw, it's a feature. Version control helps developers in following procedures and makes the procedures less painful. If you don't want to follow procedures, you don't need version control.

Answer (score 0):

Our dbas periodically check prod against what is in SVN and delete any objects not under source control. It only takes once before the devlopers never forget to put something in source control again.

We also do not allow anyone to move objects to prod without a script as our devs do not have prod rights this is easy to enforce.

Answer (score 0):

In one project I arranged by careful attention in the design that all the important data in the database can be automatically recreated from external places. At startup the application creates the database if it is missing, and populates it from external data sources, using a schema in the application source code (and hence versioned with the application).  The database store name (a sqlite filename although most database managers allow multiple databases) includes a schema version, and we increase the schema version whenever we commit a schema change. This means when we restart the application to a new version with a different schema that a new database store is automatically created and populated. Should we have to revert a deployment to an old schema then the new run of the old version will be using the old database store, so we get to do fast downgrades in the event of trouble.

Essentially, the database acts like a traditional application heap, with the advantages of persistence, transaction safety, static typing (handy since we use Python) and uniqueness constraints. However, we don't worry at all about deleting the database and starting over, and people know that if they try some manual hack in the database then it will get reverted on the next deployment, much like hacks of a process state will get reverted on the next restart.

We don't need any migration scripts since we just switch database filename and restart the application and it rebuilds itself. It helps that the application instances are sharded to use one database per client. It also reduces the need for database backups.

This approach won't work if your database build from the external sources takes longer than you will allow the application to be remain down.

Comment: This works until you have a large database full of data and you have to change the schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net and like the approach Rails takes with Migrations, then I would recommend [Migrator.Net](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/).

I found a [nice tutorial](http://michielvoo.net/blog/configuring-migrator-net-as-an-external-tool-in-visual-studio-using-msbuild/) that walks through setting it up in Visual Studio. He also provides a sample project to reference.

Answer (score 0):

We developed a custom tool that updates our databases. The database schema is stored in a database-neutral XML file which is then read and processed by the tool. The schema gets stored in SVN, and we add appropriate commentary to show what was changed. It works pretty well for us.

While this kind of solution is definitely overkill for most projects, it certainly makes life easier at times.

Answer (score 0):

In order to track all the change like insert update and delete there will be a lot of overhead for the SVN.
It is better to track only the ddl changes like (alter, drop, create) which changes the schema.
You can do this Schema tracking easily by creating a table and a trgger to insert data to that table.
Any time you want u can get the change status by querying from that table
There are a lots of example [here](http://michaelbaylon.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/automatically-tracking-database-schema-changes/) and [here](http://chrismay.org/CommentView,guid,a21c17f9-e200-4033-8309-75d6ebbc293a.aspx)