# How do shops using AccuRev handle Database changes?

Tags: version-control, accurev

We've considered using AccuRev because the stream idea makes a lot of sense for very agile shops such as ours. One question though for managing change sets: how are people handling database changes?

Does each developer have a local developer database?

And if so, how are you promoting these DB changes when you promote changes to "main" stream , or whatever it's called?

Answer (score 1):

This is a more general question of how to get your database under version control, because it is not directy dependent on Accurev. Here are some links to questions already answered:

[How do you track database changes in source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352785/how-do-you-track-database-changes-in-source-control)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952/database-version-control

And a link from Coding Horror:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/02/get-your-database-under-version-control.html

What I do is that I have .sql files to create a fresh database, another .sql scripts to update from a specific version to a new one and also backup .sql files that insert data in a database. Those are all very well maintainable text files that get handled well by source control system. The actual binary DB files are just derived objects and those should not be versioned anyway.